# Get results from HQL query with the same order as given list

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hql

I'm trying make a query with HQL that will stay with the same order as given list of IDs. I know it's possible with SQL but I can't find any way to do it with HQL (and I cannot do it with native SQL because I got many joins)

Example

fingerIds = `[3,1,10,4]`

```
SELECT p FROM People p
JOIN FETCH p.fingers f
WHERE f.id IN :fingerIds
```

DB: PostgreSQL 10.4 
Hibernate: 4.3.11.Final

Eg. Given list of IDs: `[3,1,10,4]`
Actual result's order: `[1,3,4,10]`
Expected result's order: `[3,1,10,4]`

Comment: how are you getting the given list order? Is that explicit in your code, or comes by some other column order?

Comment: It's passed to the query, check the question again, I've edited and added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the order by adding to your query the keyword `FIELD`, in your example:

```
SELECT p FROM People p
JOIN FETCH p.fingers f
WHERE f.id IN :fingerIds 
ORDER BY FIELD(f.ID,3,1,10,4)
```

Ofc you can replace the numbers with your variable `:fingerIds`

You can find more about that command [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field).
*Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list. Returns 0 if str is not found.*